# How to edit an . avi file's metadata?

Tags: multimedia

I have been looking for a solution for this little problem since Intrepid (2 years ago) and still haven't found any. EasyTag works great editing the metadata of .mp3's and I'm hoping for a similar application to edit .avi files.

Answer (score 5):

The following thread seems to have a solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=795009

However, if you do not need avi specifically, I would recommend using mkvtoolnix-gui to convert them to mkv files, which are excellent for storing video collections. It allows to add multiple audio, video and subtitle tracks, without embedding directly in the video layer. Although I never used the Tag feature, it seems you can also embed them from a xml file.

See http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge-gui.html

> Tags: For each track you can create a
>   XML tags file. For a full explanation
>   of all tags please refer to the
>   example file and mkvmerge's own
>   documentation. In probably 99% of all
>   cases you want to use THIS option and
>   associate tags with a specific track.
>   The tags option on the global tab is
>   probably not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8031373&postcount=5

Comment: Can you edit the steps from your link back into your answer please? Answers that are barely more than a link are susceptible to linkrot and hence [subject to deletion](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion) as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). Thanks!